# Print a Document with A6 format over JS Print Manager on A6 paper with ricoh mp c2004

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to print a PDF-Document with JS Print Manager The document itself actually has A6 dimensions and I want to print it on an A6 paper.

So when I set

```
const handlePrint = () => {
print({
  printable: pdfDocument.current,
  type: 'html',
  maxWidth: 800,
  paperSize: { width: '105mm', height: '148mm', unit: 'mm' }, // A6 paper size
});
};
```

The printer (ricoh mp c2004) is still trying to use A4 paper.
Do I need to specify a custom paper in the printer?
Or is there another parameter for the paper format which should be used?